# How to fix text with limited height and absolute position overflows

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I did this neat heading for a website using Bootstrap and some CSS tricks : http://www.bootply.com/QH5olSGxDU

But when using a smartphone with small width (such as an iPhone), the text overflows as shown here : http://imgur.com/k6JaKbi

Have you any idea how to prevent this (idealy by cropping the title like "Some Stuff #6 - Lorem...")? I tried the CSS property `text-overflow`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: You could try adding `min-width` like this: http://www.bootply.com/KpOx9JzTRQ but I don't think it's an ideal solution, more work needed on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use media queries to reduce the font size of the `<h2>` when the screen size is smaller than a certain size.

```
@media (max-width: 400px){
  div.header-image-single h2 { font-size: 16px; }
}
```

Alternatively, you could use javascript to check the window size and if it is smaller than a certain value trim certain tags to a set number of characters.

```
var str = originalString.substring(0, X); //original string comes directly from the content of the <h2>, the 0 is the starting position and the X is the number of characters you want to keep
```

here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/3q26N/) that shows this alternative in action (I utilized jQuery to make the selection/manipulation of elements easy, but it would be done with plain JS too)

Comment: I does just what I need. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
h2 {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 300px; (I've used this to test without a mobile device)
}
```

?

You could only apply `white-space: nowrap;` in your mobile css if desired.

Answer (score 1):

Beside adjusting the font size of the text you can also add simple min-height to the image.

.header-image img {min-height: 275px;width: 100%;}